# What is an efficient in place way of sorting an array based on an index array?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, indices

In certain machine learning algorithms the columns of the matrix are rotated and sorted based relevance of each column. New data to come should be transformed in the same order. So if my initial sort gives me [0,2,1,3] as an index array, than new data should also be ordered in this way: first, third, second, fourth element. That's why I wanted to create a sorted index array, that could later on be used as a source for reordering new data. I've managed to do that in the implementation below.

My question is about the use of the index array for reoordering new data. In my implementation I first create a clone of the new data array. Than it's easy to just copy elements from my source array to the proper index in the target array. Is this the most efficient way to do it? Or is there a more efficient way, for instance by sorting the data in place?

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;

public class IndexSorter<T> {

   private final int[] indices;
   private final int[] reverted;

   public IndexSorter(T[] data, Comparator<T> comparator){
     
     // generate index array based on initial data and a comparator:
     indices = IntStream.range(0, data.length)
                        .boxed()
                        .sorted( (a, b) -> comparator.compare(data[a],data[b]))
                        .mapToInt(a -> a)
                        .toArray();

     // also create an index array to be able to revert the sort
     reverted = new int[indices.length];
     for(int i=0;i<indices.length;i++){
       reverted[indices[i]] = i;
     }
   }

   // sort new data based on initial array
   public T[] sort(T[] data){
     return sortUsing(data, indices);
   }
   
   // revert sorted data 
   public T[] revert(T[] data){
     return sortUsing(data, reverted);
   }

   private T[] sortUsing(T[] data, int[] ind){
     if(data.length != indices.length){
       throw new IllegalArgumentException(
         String.format("Data length does not match: (%s, should be: %s) "
         ,  data.length, indices.length));
     }
     // create a copy of the data (efficively this just creates a new array)
     T[] sorted = data.clone();
     // fill the copy with the sorted data
     IntStream.range(0, ind.length)
              .forEach(i -> sorted[i]=data[ind[i]]);
     return sorted;
   }
}

class App {
  public static void main(String args[]){
      IndexSorter<String> sorter = new IndexSorter<>(args, String::compareTo);
      String[] data = sorter.sort(args);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
      data = sorter.revert(data);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
      data = IntStream.range(0, data.length)
                                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                                .toArray(String[]::new);
      data = sorter.sort(data);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
      data = sorter.revert(data);
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want to sort an array, java library methods will probably be more efficient

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend copying data. Because this is a memory allocation that can be quite expensive. It is much more efficient to sort data in place with library methods, like as `Arrays.sort`

Comment: Hi @Segey, thank you for your recommendation. I could create an empty Object array and cast it to T{} instead of using data.clone(). And I would like to use Arrays.sort, but there is no way that I can think of that Arrays.sort allows me to use the index array to reorder new data. so the point is that my initial sorted index array gives me a fixed order to use for new data.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to sort in place, using a BitSet to keep track of what indexes are having the right element. It is in the method sortUsing. I hope someone will have a use for this algorithm.

You can test it like this:

```
java App this is just some random test to show the result
```

Then outcome will first show you the sorted result, than the reverted result.
The same index array is also used for ordering an int array of indexes, and the reverted version:

```
[is, just, random, result, show, some, test, the, this, to]
[this, is, just, some, random, test, to, show, the, result]
[1, 2, 4, 9, 7, 3, 5, 8, 0, 6]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
import java.util.*;

public class IndexSorter<T> {

  private final int[] indices;
  private final int[] reverted;
  private final BitSet done;

  public IndexSorter(T[] data, Comparator<T> comparator){

    // generate index array based on initial data and a comparator:
    indices = IntStream.range(0, data.length)
                       .boxed()
                       .sorted( (a, b) -> comparator.compare(data[a],data[b]))
                       .mapToInt(a -> a)
                       .toArray();

    // also create an index array to be able to revert the sort
    reverted = new int[indices.length];
    for(int i=0;i<indices.length;i++){
      reverted[indices[i]] = i;
    }
    done = new BitSet(data.length);
  }

  // sort new data based on initial array
  public void sort(T[] data){
    sortUsing(data, indices);
  }

  // revert sorted data 
  public void revert(T[] data){
    sortUsing(data, reverted);
  }

  private void sortUsing(T[] data, int[] ind){
    if(data.length != indices.length){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException(
          String.format("Data length does not match: (%s, should be: %s) "
            ,  data.length, indices.length));
    }
    int ia=0, ib=0, x = 0;
    T a = null, b = null;
    for (int i=0; i< data.length && done.cardinality()<data.length; i++){
      ia = i;
      ib = ind[ia];
      if(done.get(ia)){ // index is already done
        continue;
      } 
      if(ia==ib){       // element is at the right place
        done.set(ia);
        continue;
      }
      x = ia;           // start a loop at x = ia 
                        // some next index will be x again eventually
      a = data[ia];     // keep element a as the last value after the loop 
      while(ib!=x && !done.get(ia) ){
        b = data[ib];   // element from index b must go to index a 
        data[ia]=b;
        done.set(ia);
        ia = ib;
        ib = ind[ia];   // get next index
      }
      data[ia]=a;       // set value a to last index
      done.set(ia);
    }
    done.clear();
  }
}

class App {
  public static void main(String args[]){
    IndexSorter<String> sorter = new IndexSorter<>(args, String::compareTo);
    sorter.sort(args);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    sorter.revert(args);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(args));
    String[] data = IntStream.range(0, args.length)
      .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
      .toArray(String[]::new);
    sorter.sort(data);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
    sorter.revert(data);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(data));
  }
}
```